# DispatchQueue Sync Concurrent

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Ok so I have gone through a ton of questions and answers and I know the understanding of it, but when I am trying some code, I am getting some results that doesnt stand by those theories.

What I understand till now :

1. Sync : Control will return once all tasks inside the block will be executed.
2. Async : Control will return immediately after the block is hit.

This is the part that seems fine.
Now comes the tricky part

1. Serial : Tasks will be performed in a serial way inside the block.
   Q1 : does this apply to tasks inside the block? as it is already happening in all scenario. Also for sync serial queues, adding tasks in different block does not matter, as control will return once the first task is done.

Eg-

```
 let syncQ = DispatchQueue(label:"xyz") // by default it is serial
  syncQ.sync{
      for _ in 0...10{
          print("ABC")
      }
  }

  syncQ.sync{
      for _ in 0...10{
          print("XYZ")
      }
  }
```

Expected Output : ABC * 10 , XYZ * 10
This is fine.

Now when I introduce concurrent serial Q, the output is same. So my question is as concurrent queues say that tasks will be done in the same time or concurrently, it isnt happening.

Eg -

```
let syncConc = DispatchQueue(label:"con",attributes:.concurrent)
syncConc.sync{
       for _ in 0...10{
          print("XYZ")
       }

       for _ in 0...10{
          print("ABC")
       }

}


  syncConc.sync{
       for _ in 0...10{
          print("HHH")
       }

       for _ in 0...10{
          print("XXX")
       }

}
```

Output : XYZ *10 ,ABC*10, HHH*10, XXX*10

So it seems that Synchronous Concurrent Queue, act like serial Queues, and only way to make concurrent operations is that if we throw a Asynchronous queue in between the action.
So from this I cannot understand, what is the purpose of concurrent type of serial queues.

If anyone can give coded examples, it will be much appreciated, as I already know the theory and working of it.
Much appreciated.

Comment: what is the purpose of concurrent type of serial queues ??? How did you deduce that serial queue could be concurrent? the queue is serial OR concurrent. it is so easy

Comment: Doesnt have to figure it out? as we are given option for makning serial queue concurrent. 
My question is that, adding multiple tasks in a single serial queue, that is supposed to be concurrent. In documentation it says this should happen, also in all the explanatory tutorials it again says so, 
But it isnt happening when I am trying to do the same thing.
Maybe its something I am missing

Comment: Where is the information from? The queue is serial if all tasks dispatched to it are executed serially. The queue is concurrent if all tasks dispatched to it are executed concurrently. Please, check again the documentation or see http://iosbrain.com/blog/2017/02/06/concurrency-in-ios-queues-and-other-definitions-in-grand-central-dispatch-gcd-with-swift-3/

Comment: Sorry, what i mean to say is : Sync - Concurrent queues, thats what my question is about. I do get queues are of types : Serial and concurrent.
But when i create a queue that is concurrent and Sync, it does NOT behave as it is said to be.
Hope i could clear the confusion

Comment: It does. Sync means, that the thread from where you are dispatching the task to queue is blocked until the task will finish execution (on some thread). You can dispatch more sync tasks at the same time from different threads. All tasks will be executed concurrently. In your example you dispatch from main, main is blocked while task is executing and after that you dispatch other task ...

Comment: Please try to understand my question first.
I am asking that I am adding multiple tasks in the same sync queue. that queue is configured as concurrent. Now isnt the tasks supposed to run concurrent in those? as mentioned in various tutorials .

Comment: You added the second task when the first finished. Not the concurrent queue, but you did it!

Comment: Yes but i wanna ask that it is possible as in tutorials to work multiple tasks in concurrent way in a sync queue. I am asking about how to do it. as this way it is not done, and i can understand why

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're mixing up the queue types and the execution model.

There are serial and concurrent queues, and you can dispatch tasks to **both** types synchronously or asynchronously.

A queue can be:

- Serial -> Executes only one task at a time
- Concurrent -> It can run multiple tasks at the same time

And we can submit a task to a queue:

- Synchronously -> The caller needs to wait until that task returns
- Asynchronously -> The caller code regains control without having to wait for the task to finish

To sum it up:

- The serial or concurrent type of a queue determines whether it can execute one or more tasks at the same time
- Scheduling a task synchronously or asynchronously determine when the caller’s code regains control

Answer (score 6):

Actually, It looks like In your code when you are executing the task in concurrent queue (second snippet) you are dispatching the task through sync block, So that will block the current thread as per the sync behaviour.

**"Sync : Control will return once all tasks inside the block will be executed.”**

```
   let syncConc = DispatchQueue(label:"con",attributes:.concurrent)

   syncConc.sync{
      for _ in 0...10{
        print("XYZ")
      }

      for _ in 0...10{
        print("ABC")
      }
   }


   syncConc.sync{
      for _ in 0...10{
        print("HHH")
      }

      for _ in 0...10{
        print("XXX")
      }
   }
```

So, Here In this case first the suncConc queue will dispatch the first sync block, now since it is blocking call, Next task is not going to be dispatched immediately, It will be dispatched, Once the first will be completed and then It will be dispatched in suncConc queue and again executed with blocking call.

Now, let me come to your query

**"Now when I introduce concurrent serial Q, the output is same. So my question is as concurrent queues say that tasks will be done in the same time or concurrently, it isnt happening."**

Yes, sync operations can also concurrently perform but It is only possible when you dispatch both the calls immediately without blocking current thread. Check following snippet, The two sync tasks are dispatched from different queue, Hence It will be executed concurrently.

```
    let syncConc = DispatchQueue(label:"con",attributes:.concurrent)


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        syncConc.sync{
            for _ in 0...10{
                print("XYZ - \(Thread.current)")
            }
            for _ in 0...10{
                print("ABC - \(Thread.current)")
            }
        }
    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        syncConc.sync{
            for _ in 0...10{
                print("HHH - \(Thread.current)")
            }

            for _ in 0...10{
                print("XXX - \(Thread.current)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Execute the code & See the magic all the theories will be apply as expected :)

Comment: I am getting a bit confused that why this would work? Dispatch a concurrent sync task in a global queue, so why do we need the concurrent sync task in the first place?

Comment: There's no such thing as "concurrent sync task." Queues can be concurrent, and tasks can be dispatched synchronously or asynchronously to a queue.

Answer (score 4):

A few terminology observations:

- The terms “synchronous” and “asynchronous” dictate the behavior of the caller. It governs whether the calling thread will wait for the dispatched item or not.
- The terms “serial“ and “concurrent” define the behavior of the queue to which you are dispatching. It dictates whether the queue can run two separately dispatched items on separate worker threads at the same time or not.

It is important to not conflate these terms. Synchronous/asynchronous dictates the calling thread’s behavior. Serial/concurrent dictates the dispatch queue behavior.

With that aside, a few observations:

- Consider:

  ```swift
  queue.sync {
      for _ in 0...10 {
          print("ABC")
      }
  }

  // because above is `sync`, calling thread won't even get here until the
  // code dispatched above is finished; it is irrelevant whether the queue 
  // is serial or concurrent.

  queue.sync {
      for _ in 0...10 {
          print("XYZ")
      }
  }
  ```

  In this case, it doesn't matter if `queue` is a serial queue or a concurrent queue: Because you used `sync`, it will not reach any of the `XYZ` lines until the `ABC` lines are all done.
- If you want to see concurrent behavior, you must use `async`, not `sync`. If you want them to run at the same time, you do not want the caller waiting for the first dispatched item to finish before submitting the second one. You want it to submit one work item and not wait before submitting the second.

  Consider:

  ```swift
  let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")
  let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrent", attributes: .concurrent)

  serialQueue.async {
      // A
  }

  serialQueue.async {
      // B
  }

  concurrentQueue.async {
      // C
  }

  concurrentQueue.async {
      // D
  }
  ```

  Here is a graph of those four tasks (each spinning for one second) using the “Points of Interest” tool in the Instruments’ timeline:

  [image]

  Because we used `async` rather than `sync`, you now can see that the concurrent queue ran C and D concurrently, whereas the serial queue ran A and B sequentially.

---

While not central to my observations, for the sake of completeness, here is the actual code used above:

```swift
import os.log

func gcdExperiment() {
    let pointsOfInterest = OSSignposter(subsystem: "log", category: .pointsOfInterest)

    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")
    let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrent", attributes: .concurrent)

    serialQueue.async {
        pointsOfInterest.withIntervalSignpost("serial", "A") {
            self.spin(for: .seconds(1))
        }
    }

    serialQueue.async {
        pointsOfInterest.withIntervalSignpost("serial", "B") {
            self.spin(for: .seconds(1))
        }
    }

    concurrentQueue.async {
        pointsOfInterest.withIntervalSignpost("concurrent", "C") {
            self.spin(for: .seconds(1))
        }
    }

    concurrentQueue.async {
        pointsOfInterest.withIntervalSignpost("concurrent", "D") {
            self.spin(for: .seconds(1))
        }
    }
}

func spin(for delay: Duration) {
    let start = ContinuousClock.now

    while start.duration(to: .now) < delay { }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

to be able to see what is the difference between the serial/concurrent queue and between sync / async method and how they are dispatched to the queue, try to play with next snippet on you Playground.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Dispatch
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let q = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrect queue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)

func runner0(queue: DispatchQueue) {
    for _ in 1..<10 {
        let result = queue.sync { ()->Int in
            usleep(100)
            return 0
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(result, "-")
        }
    }
}

func runner1(queue: DispatchQueue) {
    for _ in 1..<10 {
        let result = queue.sync { ()->Int in
            usleep(100)
            return 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("-", result)
        }
    }
}

let arr = [runner0, runner1]

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 2) { (i) in
    arr[i](q)
}
```

We have **one concurrent** queue, where two different **runners are dispatching tasks synchronously**. As you can see, all the **task in our concurrent queue are executed concurrently**, the result is then **printed serially (asynchronously)** on the serial queue.

I hope, this helps you to see how it works.

My Playground prints

```
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
- 1
```

**let's make the queue to be serial** by changing its definition

```
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "serial queue")
```

and compare what we have as a result

```
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
0 -
- 1
```